# After updating Invantive Control fo Excel, I get the error: 'itgenefn003' after synchronizing my model to import data from Exact Online

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control, exact-online

After an update of Invantive Control for Excel I get the following error when I synchronize my model to import data from Exact Online:

[image]

> **ITGENEFN003**

```
Type: Invantive.Configuration.InvantiveSystemException   
bij Invantive.Configuration.ValidationException..ctor(String errorCode, String errorMessage, String kindRequest, String localStackTrace, String nk, Exception innerException)   
bij Invantive.Configuration.InvantiveSystemException..ctor(String validationCode, String errorMessage, String kindRequest, String stackTrace, String nk, Exception innerException)   
bij Invantive.Data.EntityFieldCollection.get_Item(String name)   
bij Invantive.Producer.Control.UdfExactOnline.GetEolBudgetLinePeriodInformation(String fieldName, String divisionCode, String budgetScenarioCode, Int64 budgetFinancialYear, Int64 budgetFinancialPeriodFrom, Int64 budgetFinancialPeriodTo, String glAccountCode, String glAccountType, String glAccountBalanceType, String reportingSchemeCode, String classificationCode, String costUnitCode, String costCentreCode, String itemCode, String executionHint, Boolean isNoValueNA, ResultAggregationMethod resultAggregationMethod)   
bij Invantive.Producer.Control.UdfHub.GetEolBudgetLinePeriodInformation(String fieldName, String divisionCode, String budgetScenarioCode, Int32 budgetFinancialYear, Int32 budgetFinancialPeriodFrom, Int32 budgetFinancialPeriodTo, String glAccountCode, String glAccountType, String glAccountBalanceType, String reportingSchemeCode, String classificationCode, String costUnitCode, String costCentreCode, String itemCode, String executionHint, Boolean isNoValueNA, ResultAggregationMethod resultAggregationMethod)   bij System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)   bij Invantive.Data.EntityFieldCollection.get_Item(String name) in File264:regel 358 bij Invantive.Producer.Control.UdfExactOnline.GetEolBudgetLinePeriodInformation(String fieldName, String divisionCode, String budgetScenarioCode, Int64 budgetFinancialYear, Int64 budgetFinancialPeriodFrom, Int64 budgetFinancialPeriodTo, String glAccountCode, String glAccountType, String glAccountBalanceType, String reportingSchemeCode, String classificationCode, String costUnitCode, String costCentreCode, String itemCode, String executionHint, Boolean isNoValueNA, ResultAggregationMethod resultAggregationMethod) in File160:regel 1595
```

This error occurs for every cell on the worksheet. After clicking 'ok' it gives the same error for the next cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itgenefn003 occurs when the spreadsheet formulas have not been updated to the latest version of the xlam. The easiest way to fix this is to re-install the software. This repairs the xlam file associated with the software.

Did a new install help?